# error .../node_modules/coa: Command failed

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, vue-cli

I'm getting following error while trying creating a vue3's app via Vue-cli `vue create project`

```
✨  Creating project in /home/iraj/works/project.
⚙️  Installing CLI plugins. This might take a while...

yarn install v1.22.17
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
[1/4] ⠄ core-js
[2/4] ⠄ coa
[3/4] ⠄ ejs
error /home/iraj/works/project/node_modules/coa: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: start /B node compile.js & node compile.js
Arguments: 
Directory: /home/iraj/works/project/node_modules/coa
Output:
/bin/sh: 1: start: not found
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/iraj/works/project/node_modules/coa/compile.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}



 ERROR  command failed: yarn
```

tools I'm using:

```
  System:
    OS: Linux 5.11 Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4702MQ CPU @ 2.20GHz
  Binaries:
    Node: 17.0.1 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.17 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 8.1.2 - /usr/local/bin/npm
  Browsers:
    Chrome: Not Found
    Firefox: 93.0
  npmGlobalPackages:
    @vue/cli: 4.5.15
```

Comment: thanks mate, yes, the same error.

Answer (score 0):

solved. just removed the directory `/home/iraj/works/project/node_modules/coa` and run again `vue create project` in `Merge` mode

Answer (score 0):

COA was compromised, hence causing this error. Check https://github.com/veged/coa/issues/99